# Why reactive-table is empty?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have no luck to make reactive-table to work. Table is empty but data from collection is visible in browser console.

Client side:

```
Template.devices.helpers({
    Devices : function(){
       return Devices;
    }
});
```

Route:

```
Router.route('/devices', function(){
    Meteor.subscribe('devices');
    this.render('devices');
    this.layout("defaultLayout");
});
```

Template:

```
<template name="devices">
   {{> reactiveTable collection=Devices}}
</template>
```

Server side:

```
Meteor.publish('devices', function () {
        return Devices.find();
    });
```

What have I missed?

Comment: helpers `return Devices.find();` on the client side you also use mongo (minimongo) like on server side and you still have to do the same queries but it's done on what has been sent from the server and available on the client. (on server you do that query to the database)

Comment: update: you use reactiveTable doesn't it handle the publishing and subsription? It should do it for you. Check the docs.

Comment: Documentation tells that I need to create and subscribe to a collection, and pass it to the template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've passed array to table and all works fine

```
Template.devices.helpers({
    Devices : function(){
       return Devices.find().fetch();
    }
});
```